# web.config c# .net web application

Tags: c#, .net, web, web-config

How to read a personal section in a web.config ?

```
<MyPersonalSection>
    <add name="toto" enable="true" URL="http://localhost:43242" />
    <add name="titi" enable="false" URL="http://localhost:98762" />
<MyPersonalSection/>
```

I'd like to get the enable value and/or URL value with the name value.

I also have this mistake : Unrecognized configuration section MyPersonalSection

I been trying

var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyPersonalSection");

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Comment: <add... is a key/value idiom  (e.g. only two attributes), it's confusing to add three attributes to an add element.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) is a cool example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a custom configuration handler to get what you want.  There are built-in configuration handlers that you can use if you simply want key-value entries.  But, you'll have to use `key` instead of `name` and `value` instead of `URL`.  For example:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="MyPersonalSection" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
 </configSections>
<MyPersonalSection>
    <add key="toto" value="http://localhost:43242" />
    <add key="titi" value="http://localhost:98762" />
</MyPersonalSection>
</configuration>
```

And you can access them via code:

```
var myValues = ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("MyPersonalSection") as NameValueCollection;
var url = myValues["toto"];
```

I would suggest naming your keys in a way that makes it clear what the value should be, like "totoUrl" and "titiUrl".

If you want something other than string value pairs, you'll have to write your own custom handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tried that but in my case, it doen't work. I forgot to say that I have 3 values, I edited my first message.

Comment: Then you'll need to write you own handler, see laszlokiss88 's answer for a reference.

Comment: @Vinhent Writing a custom section handler sometimes requires processing XML text in some way; but, usually you can create classes to represent elements as described in the link that laszlokiss88 provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can add appSettings section in your web.config with key that you will need. For example:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="FirstUrl" value="http://localhost:43242"/>
      <add key="SecondUrl" value="http://localhost:98762" />
    </appSettings>
 ...
</configuration>
```

So, since aspx.cs file, you can declare directive

```
using System.Configuration;
```

And later, you can retrieve FirstUrl value in this way:

```
 var myUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirstUrl"];
```